# MSAGL: How to neutralize the graphics transform in DrawNodeDelegate so that owner drawing can always begin with top left as 0,0?

Tags: winforms, transform, gdi, coordinate-systems, msagl

I am using a `NodeBoundaryDelegate` to owner-draw my nodes.

Is it possible to neutralize the graphics transform in DrawNodeDelegate so that this owner drawing can always begin with top left of the relevant area as 0,0?

`Msagl.Drawing.Node`'s coordinate system is positive-y-is-north. Winforms is positive-y-is-south.

In my graph (about 100 nodes, laid out very wide from left to right) the leftmost Msagl.Drawing.Node objects usually end up at coordinates like -10,000, -3000.

`g.ClipBounds` ends up with ranges like {X = -10019.999 Y = -1716.70862 Width = 9519.998 Height = 3755.74536}.

By the time the code reaches `DrawNode`, g.Transform already is already in some (non-intutive to me) nonzero range like:

```
[0]   0.0612394959
[1]   0
[2]   0
[3]   0.0612394959
[4]   613.619751
[5]   224.130356
```

In case it matters, I *am* also using `NodeBoundaryDelegate` to hardcode all my node sizes to a fixed size of 500x50.

```cs
private bool DrawNode(Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Node node, object graphics)
{
    Graphics g = (Graphics)graphics;

    // some kind of g.Transform wizardry here?

    g.DrawString("nodename", Font, Brushes.Red, 0, 0);  // 0,0 should be perfectly aligned
                                                        // at top left corner of drawn node
}
```

Comment: [Graphics.TranslateTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.translatetransform). Probably simpler when used with a Matrix: some notes and an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53182901/7444103)

Comment: Thanks. `g.TranslateTransform((float)node.BoundingBox.Left, (float)node.BoundingBox.Top);` did work. It's kind of unsatisfying not being able to understand exactly _how_ it works, but it got the job done. Add as solution and I can upvote.